# Running an event loop within its own thread

Tags: python, python-multithreading, python-asyncio

I'm playing with Python's new(ish) `asyncio` stuff, trying to combine its event loop with traditional threading. I have written a class that runs the event loop in its own thread, to isolate it, and then provide a (synchronous) method that runs a coroutine on that loop and returns the result. (I realise this makes it a somewhat pointless example, because it necessarily serialises everything, but it's just as a proof-of-concept).

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from threading import Thread


class Fetcher(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        # FIXME Do I need this? It works either way...
        #asyncio.set_event_loop(self._loop)

        self._session = aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=self._loop)

        self._thread = Thread(target=self._loop.run_forever)
        self._thread.start()

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *e):
        self._session.close()
        self._loop.call_soon_threadsafe(self._loop.stop)
        self._thread.join()
        self._loop.close()

    def __call__(self, url:str) -> str:
        # FIXME Can I not get a future from some method of the loop?
        future = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self._get_response(url), self._loop)
        return future.result()

    async def _get_response(self, url:str) -> str:
        async with self._session.get(url) as response:
            assert response.status == 200
            return await response.text()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Fetcher() as fetcher:
        while True:
            x = input("> ")

            if x.lower() == "exit":
                break

            try:
                print(fetcher(x))
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"WTF? {e.__class__.__name__}")
```

To avoid this sounding too much like a "Code Review" question, what is the purpose of `asynchio.set_event_loop` and do I need it in the above? It works fine with and without. Moreover, is there a loop-level method to invoke a coroutine and return a future? It seems a bit odd to do this with a module level function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to use `set_event_loop` if you called `get_event_loop` anywhere and wanted it to return the loop created when you called `new_event_loop`.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.new_event_loop)

> If there’s need to set this loop as the event loop for the current context, `set_event_loop()` must be called explicitly.

Since you do not call `get_event_loop` anywhere in your example, you can omit the call to `set_event_loop`.

Comment: What does "context" mean here? It can't mean "scope" as then there would be no need to call `set_event_loop` anywhere, unless for the odd case where you had multiple loops in the same scope. Is it a good idea to use `set_event_loop` regardless of the lack of `get_event_loop`, just in case the latter is called elsewhere in the codebase?

Comment: It will vary based on the policy used, but [the default policy defines context as the current thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloops.html#event-loop-policies-and-the-default-policy). And yes, if there's a chance the same loop will be used elsewhere, then you should call `set_event_loop`.

Comment: If the default policy "manages an event loop per thread", does that mean I don't explicitly need to call `asyncio.new_event_loop()`? That is, does each thread have an implicit event loop, which will be returned by `get_event_loop` when it's called within the same context? (Obviously, in my code above, I create a new loop *outside* the new thread, but that can be changed easily enough.)

Comment: Correct. You can start with a call to `get_event_loop`. You only need to use `new_event_loop` when you don't want that loop or it's been closed.

Comment: Awesome: Thanks :)

Comment: I might be misinterpreting, but i think the comment by @dirn is incorrect in stating that `get_event_loop` works from a thread. I added clarification in a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I might be misinterpreting, but i think the comment by @dirn in the marked answer is incorrect in stating that `get_event_loop` works from a thread. See the following example:

```
import asyncio
import threading

async def hello():
    print('started hello')
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print('finished hello')

def threaded_func():
    el = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    el.run_until_complete(hello())

thread = threading.Thread(target=threaded_func)
thread.start()
```

This produces the following error:

```
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'.
```

It can be fixed by:

```
 - el = asyncio.get_event_loop()
 + el = asyncio.new_event_loop()
```

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.get_event_loop) also specifies that this trick (creating an eventloop by calling `get_event_loop`) only works on the main thread:

> If there is no current event loop set in the current OS thread, the OS thread is main, and set_event_loop() has not yet been called, asyncio will create a new event loop and set it as the current one.

Finally, the docs also recommend to use `get_running_loop` instead of `get_event_loop` if you're on version 3.7 or higher

Comment: I am pretty sure they meant to say- call `set_event_loop()` before calling `get_event_loop()` but yeah `get_running_loop()` sounds better.